# Nested struct attributes inheritance

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual

I read that you can extend a structure by using inheritance. I have a derived class in which I want to have the same struct that its parent but extended with more fields. This seems to work, however when I call a method from the Parent class that modified the structure, it does not have effect in the Child structure attribute. Here, an example of what am I trying:

```cpp
class Parent
{
  public:

    struct info 
    {
      int a;
    };

    info data;
    virtual void main(void);

};

void Parent::main()
{
  data.a =1;
}

class Child: public Parent
{
  public:

  struct info2: public info
  {
    int b;
  };

  info2 data;
  virtual void main(void);
};

void Child::main(void)
{
  Parent::main();
  data.b = 2;
  std::cout << data.a << "\n";
  std::cout << data.b << "\n";
}

int main(void)
{
  Parent *base;
  Child derived;
  base = &derived;

  base->main();

  return 0;
}
```

This instead of printing `1 and 2` prints `0 and 2`. So basically as if the attribute data from the derived class is not modified by the call to `Parent::main`.

What the right way of doing that? Am I completely doing it wrong?

Comment: As an aside, `void` in parameter lists has no effect in C++, unlike in C.

Answer (score 1):

You mean

```
void Child::main(void)
{
  Parent::main();
  data.b = 2;
  std::cout << Parent::data.a << "\n";
  std::cout << data.b << "\n";
}
```

The name `data` declared in the derived class hides the name `data` declared in the base class. So you need to use a qualified name to access a hidden member of the parent class.

As for data member `a` of the member data of the derived class then it was not initialized.

Objects of the derived class have two data members `data`: one is inherited with the type info (which name is hidden in the derived class) and other is the own data member of the derived class.

The base class knows nothing about the data member `data` of the derived class.

You could define a virtual function within the class info. For example

```
#include <iostream>
class Parent
{
  public:

    struct info 
    {
      int a;
      virtual void set( int a )
      {
        this->a = a;
      }
    };

    info data;
    virtual void main(void);

};

void Parent::main()
{
  data.set( 1 );
}

class Child: public Parent
{
  public:

  struct info2: public info
  {
    int b;
    void set( int a ) override
    {
        this->a = a;
    }
  };

  info2 data;
  virtual void main(void);
};

void Child::main(void)
{
    data.set( 3 );
  data.b = 2;
  std::cout << data.a << "\n";
  std::cout << data.b << "\n";
}

int main(void)
{
  Parent *base;
  Child derived;
  base = &derived;

  base->main();

  return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
3
2
```

Comment: Can't I make the data.a from `Child` be the same than the Parent one? Somehow I want that the child has data.a filled by the parent and its contained in the `Childs` struct.

Comment: @edgarstack In the parent class you did not initialize the data member a. The base class knows nothing about the new structure info2 of the derived class.

Comment: Well, I want the `Parent::main()` method to modify `Child::data.a`. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: @edgarstack No there is no way. Base classes know nothing about which new data members their derived classes have.

Comment: So maybe I am approaching this from the wrong angle. Is there a better/more correct way of doing what I am trying to do? So basically: Parent class has a struct that is modified by its methods. Then the Child wants to add some new information unique for the child in the same structure. However, I want to combine (and reuse) calls to Parent's methods with Child methods to fill the structure.

Comment: In this case, @edgarstack, you would most likely need to use `data` polymorphically, too.

Comment: Any pointers on how to use `data` polymorphically?  I know how to do it with class methods, but not with struct members.

Comment: Thanks for the example. The only problem is that you had to call the `Set(3)` in the Child, but what I want to do is `Parent::main()` to do the set. In the example I posted here the functions are just a mock, in my real case the Parent::main() is doing a lot of things until it knows what to set as a value to all the members (there are many more too). So I just wanted to avoid copying the Parents::main to the Child, cuz a solution would be to duplicate the code, but is not elegant nor robust.

Answer (score 1):

You're entirely correct, `Parent::main()` is unable to access `Child::data`, and knows nothing about any mythical `info2` type; to it, `Parent::data` is all there is, and `info` is its type.

There are a few easy ways to make `Child::main()` work with `Child::data` instead of `Parent::data`, or to make it access the desired field from each version, but I suspect that's not what you're after.  If you want both `Parent` and `Child` to see the same `data` (as an `info` and an `info2`, respectively), then `data` should itself be used polymorphically.  For this example, I'll use a regular pointer for simplicity (and in turn, `operator.` will be replaced with `operator->`, when accessing `data`'s members), but I would recommend looking into smart pointers such as `std::unique_ptr` to simplify the memory management.

```
class Parent
{
  public:

    struct info 
    {
      int a;

      // Chances are, it's going to be deleted through an info* no matter what it is.  Therefore, virtual destructor.
      virtual ~info() = default;
    };

    info* data;  // Consider using a smart pointer here, like std::unique_ptr.
    virtual void main(void);
    virtual void output() const; // Just adding this for convenience.

    // Default constructor now allows data to be supplied, or creates it if necessary.
    Parent(info* dp = nullptr) : data(dp ? dp : new info) {}
    // Correct destructor will always be called.
    virtual ~Parent() { if(data) { delete data; } }

};

void Parent::main()
{
  data->a =1;
}
```

We now remove the field `Child::data`, and instead have `Child` supply its desired `data` to `Parent`'s constructor.

```
class Child: public Parent
{
  public:

  struct info2: public info
  {
    int b;
  };

  //info2 data;
  virtual void main(void);
  void output() const override; // Just adding this for convenience.

  Child() : Parent(new info2) {}
};
```

`Child` will, when required, view `data` as an `info2` instead of an `info`.

```
void Child::main(void)
{
  Parent::main();
  auto dataPtr = static_cast<info2*>(data); // In Child, we know data is an info2*.
  dataPtr->b = 2;

  // Just gonna move these to output(), for a cleaner illustration.
  //std::cout << "Data->a: " << data->a << "\n";
  //std::cout << "Data->b: " << dataPtr->b << "\n";
}
```

This will then cause `data` to work as desired, with `Parent` and `Child` both having the correct type.

```
void Parent::output() const {
  std::cout << "Parent:\n";
  std::cout << "> Data->a: " << data->a << "\n";
}

void Child::output() const /*override*/ {
  std::cout << "Child as ";
  Parent::output();

  auto dataPtr = static_cast<info2*>(data);
  std::cout << "Child:\n";
  std::cout << "> Data->a: " << dataPtr->a << "\n";
  std::cout << "> Data->b: " << dataPtr->b << "\n";
}
```

This will then perform as expected, as seen [live on Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f4a9d8613b073d95).  Note that if you want to be able to, e.g., create a `Child` from a pre-existing `Parent`, you'll want to add a move constructor that can make an `info2` from an `info`; you should consider following the [Rule of Five](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4172724/5386374), or using a smart pointer instead of a raw pointer. ;P

Comment: amazing! thats what I wanted. Is there any place I can learn these things properly? I don't think I will find this in a standard C++ book.

Comment: I'm sure there are books that teach as least some of this stuff, @edgarstack; I'd be surprised if the Rule of Three/Five/Zero isn't discussed anywhere.  Apart from that, CPPReference.com is a _mostly_ accurate, slightly easier-to-read reference for the C++ standard, and CPlusPlus.com is easier to read than it (albeit somewhat out of date).  There are tutorials online on sites like CProgramming.com, and a lot of good explanations on here (if you can find them). A lot of times, though, experimentation will be your best teacher, and a lot of complex tricks like this are just knowing how to use...

Comment: ...simple things you're more likely to find explained elsewhere.  (In this case, for example, I'm just applying the same principles you're learning about, inheritance & polymorphism.  Accessing `data`'s fields through a pointer here works similarly to `base->main()` dynamically choosing the correct version of `main()` to call even though `base` is ` Parent*` (because every `Child` is also a `Parent`, or more mechanically contains a `Parent` for the pointer to latch onto); the main difference is that we do the dynamic dispatch work ourself instead of it being automated by `virtual` functions.

Comment: (Also note that you need to be careful when doing something like downcasting `info*` to `info2*` with `static_cast`, though.  Downcasting by `static_cast` doesn't do any type checking, and is thus only for when you know the actual pointed-to type is-an `info2` (where "is-a(n) `X`" means "is either `X` or derived from `X`); since `Child` explicitly provides an `info2` for `data`, we can guarantee this.  You'd normally use `dynamic_cast` if you need to downcast, which would give you a `nullptr` if the object's actual type isn't actually the type you're casting it to.)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the below code:

```
void Child::main(void)
{
    Parent::main();
    data.b = 2;
    std::cout << Parent::data.a << "\n";
    std::cout << data.b << "\n";
}
```